# Implementing Lucas Rocha's smoothie

Tags: performance, listview, scroll, albumart

I am trying to implement the excellent library provided by Lucas Rocha. This library allows for very efficient scrolling on ListViews.

https://github.com/lucasr/smoothie

His text states 1.Add Smoothie's jar as a dependency to your project. but I am not able to find any jar file in the package.

I have emailed him but his response simply refers to the narrative within his modules. There is no user friendly guide on how to go about implementing this. 
It is clearly directed at experienced programmers but it would be useful if all the "not so experienced" programmers are able to progress with this.

So my question:
Can anyone provide clear step by step guidance on how to implement the smoothie libray.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The JAR needs to be compiled from source as a compiled version is not available for direct download.  You can see my [sample application](https://github.com/manish-in-java/android-phonebook) to see Smoothie in action.  The sample application also contains a JAR file compiled from the latest Smoothie source code.

At a bare minimum, you need to write two classes, one extending `android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter` and another extending `org.lucasr.smoothie.ItemLoader`.  The sample application mentioned above contains `ContactAdapter` and `ContactLoader` classes that extend these aforementioned ones.

The order in which these classes are coded does not really matter, but I found it easier to implement `ContactAdapter` and therefore coded it first.